# Is there a reason for this inconsistent Pandas behavior?

Tags: python, pandas

I have been studying Pandas during the last weeks and realized something curious about it's behavior.

Assume I have a Pandas DataFrame called `df` and assume it has two columns "A" and "B".

I would like to modify some values of the column "B" according to the code bellow, which does not work as I expected.

```py
df[df["A"] == True]["B"] = 100
```

After a little Google search, I found out that the correct way to do this is as follows:

```py
df.loc[df["A"] == True, "B"] = 100
```

I was happy with it, until I accidentally discovered that the code bellow works too.

```py
df["B"][df["A"] == True] = 100
```

The second and last methods successfully modify my DataFrame, while the first one does nothing to it.

Why does the third code work while the first one fails? Is it a matter of design decisions?

Comment: I don't know what version of Pandas you are using but I am running pandas 1.4.4 and I get the same warning for the first and third methods, the only clean result is with method 2.  The warning message is pretty explicit, with 1 or 3, you are attempting to modify a value in a copy of a slice.

Comment: Refer to this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy

Comment: I'm using Pandas 1.5.1 and I am not getting any warning message (although, of course, I understand the second method is the right one). The point of my question, which may not be well explained, is about understanding what is going on.